# Vue: Push element to array which is in object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have the following structure:

```
data: () => ({
  loadProgress: [{}]
})
```

example structure of `loadProgress`

```
[{
  itemId: 1,
  details:[{}, {}, {}]
}, {
  itemId: 2,
  details: [{}, {}, {}, {}]
}]
```

how I can do `this.loadProgress[index].details.push(...)` to achieve reactivity?

I'm rendering it with `v-for` where `:key` is `item.itemId`

Comment: Your queation is not very clear. What have you already tried. Can you give actual code you tried?

Comment: `this.loadProgress[index].details.push(...)` this is what I've already tried, I have event listener which is giving me one object which needs to be added to an array which I've mentioned earlier.

Comment: ok, can you show the v-for code and show the exact place it is not working. I understand your question, but seeing your implementation will help give a proper answer to your problem. But there are known issues with array reactivity and this link can help https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Array-Change-Detection

Answer (score 1):

You can use vue $set method. By default vue does'not wast changes on deep nested object so you should use like this:

```
this.loadProgress[index].details.$set(index, val);
or
this.$set(this.loadProgress[index].details, index, val);
```